# When does a "useEffect" with a double arrow notation get executed?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, arrow-functions

I'm using React 17.  I came across this in a component ...

```
  useEffect(
    () => () => {
        ...
    },
    [pageVar]
  );
```

What does the double arrow notation mean with regards to when this hook is executed?  I have seen a more traditional side effect ...

```
  useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, [summary]);
```

which will be executed when the summary value changes (I think) but the double arrow notation above is completely new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returning function of a `useEffect` hook is known as a "clean-up function", which is called by React when the component is unmounted.

In this case seems that the hook is *only* returning a clean-up function.

You can read more in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).